# Using diff_drive_controller for a robot with off-centre wheels

Tags: ros, diff-drive-controller, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I'm attempting to use the diff_drive_controller package in ros_control for a robot which has wheels positioned off-centre (i.e. at the front of the robot). It then has a caster wheel at the back. In reality, the robot rotates about the centre of the two front wheels. However, the odometry published by diff_drive_controller rotates the robot about the base_link. Is there a way to correct this?

Many thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253536/using-diff_drive_controller-for-a-robot-with-off-centre-wheels/) by [epsilonjon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25376/epsilonjon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2017-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The way I have achieved this is to create a link at my desired point of rotation, then to set the diff_drive_controller parameter base_frame_id equal to that link.

---

Originally posted by [epsilonjon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25376/epsilonjon/) with karma: 123 on 2017-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1